# Do downvotes affect suspended users?

Tags: support, down-votes, account-suspension

When user is suspended, his shown reputation is 1, but actual (shown when the user is not suspended) rep often isn't. Any downvotes he receive affect his shown rep (1), and I think he can't lose rep any more because downvotes are shown empty. Upvotes affect his actual rep which is increased and when suspension is over, the actual rep is shown again.

Do downvotes actually affect suspended users?

> [image: reputation log without visible downvotes]

**You see empty downvotes?**

I see now, they actually do:

> [image: reputation log with visible downvotes]

Comment: How did you test this? Once out of suspension, the downvotes most certainly show themselves in the rep, as normal.

Comment: @Oded: Even *during* suspension, the rep log shows -2 for downvotes. At least on the network-wide banned user I am looking at right now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - yes, my phrasing was poor. I meant the overall "actual" reputation.

Comment: @Oded See my screenshot. The answers and questions that got down voted are not cw. You see that because of up votes he have rep to get down voted.

Comment: @Martijn "Even during suspension, the rep log shows -2 for down votes" - It doesn't.

Comment: @nicael: it does whenever a recalculation has taken place. Recalculations take place automatically on a number of events, including lifting a suspension. As I stated before, looking at several users currently suspended I see `-2` values for downvotes in their reputation history.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When a user is unsuspended, their reputation is recalculated and everything is taken into account.

Answer (score 13):

**All votes** affect a suspended user. Effectively, only the *displayed* reputation is set to 1.

If their *actual* reputation is over 1, downvotes do affect their reputation. When the user comes out of suspension, reputation is recalculated, as if their reputation was never set to 1 to begin with.

When the user's actual rep is over 1, downvotes are shown as -2 in their reputation history:

[image]

Any entries that show no reputation change either show that the user was at 1 at that time or will be handled by a full reputation recalculation (which is applied automatically in a number of events, including when the suspension is lifted).

Comment: But it is shown empty rep for downvote every time.

Comment: @nicael: Then their *actual* reputation was **also** at 1.

Comment: Look at my screenshot.

Comment: There are other downvotes in the users history after the suspension (June 10th) that are recorded with a -2. It'll all work out in the end.